# Difference between "What does that matter?" and "Why does that matter?"

Tags: american-english, interrogatives, spoken-english

"What does that matter?" Vs "Why does that matter" What is the difference between these two?

Answer (score 9):

The difference is not as much in the expression itself as in the frequency of its use.  In most cases that I've encountered, both expressions are used to **imply** that something (the topic or the subject of the conversation) *does not matter*.

#### It's a rhetorical question.

> What does that matter?

is used ***by far*** *more often* than

> Why does that matter?

The answer to the latter is actually logically *easier to give* than the answer to the former.  The verb "matter" is **intransitive**, i.e. it does not use a direct object.  In other words, to answer the "*what does that matter?*" question (in which "what" is the object of the verb "matter") one would have to violate the grammar rules and [try to] use the verb "matter" **transitively**.

To answer "why does that matter?" one would say something like, "It matters because...", and then give the actual reason.

To answer "what does that matter?" one would try to say, "It matters..." and then *stumble* because no object can grammatically follow the verb, thus proving the point of the other party *implied* in the question "what does that matter?" (i.e. "that does **not** matter").